# How do I parse a response with Ktor

Tags: json, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to do a Get call with Ktor in a multiplatform project. This is the code:

```
private val client = HttpClient()

fun myCall(callback: (List<Film>) -> Unit) {

    viewModelScope.launch {
        val result:List<Film> = client.get {
            url("https://data.sfgov.org/resource/wwmu-gmzc.json")
        }
        callback(result)
    }
}
```

Every time I make this request the application closes and I don't receive any message that gives me a clue what's going on. If instead of putting a list Film as the result type I put String then it works and I receive a list of movies, but I want to parse it to my own objects and I am unable.

Is there something wrong with the call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the **Ktor http client** to **deserialize to your custom object**, you would need to install `JsonFeature` while creating your http client, which would need the `io.ktor:ktor-client-json` dependency added.

```
val client = HttpClient {
   install(JsonFeature)
}
```

Then depending on whichever serializer you want to use (Ktor supports **Gson**, **Jackson** and **Kotlinx.Serialization**), you need to add the dependency of the respective serializer. For eg, if you want to use `Gson`, you need to add the dependency for `io.ktor:ktor-client-gson`. Then your API response would get deserialized to your `List<Film>` object.

```
val result: List<Film> = client.get {
   url("https://data.sfgov.org/resource/wwmu-gmzc.json")
}
```

More on the above in the Ktor [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/json-feature.html)

Answer (score 3):

For your `result`, you could also try using `HttpResponse` as a type.

And I think, you then still have to explicitly use the library (e.g. `Gson`) to parse the api-response, e.g.

```
val result: HttpResponse = client.get("https://data.sfgov.org/resource/wwmu-gmzc.json")
val parsedResponseBody = Gson().fromJson(result.readText(), Films::class.java)
```

`readText()` is an extension function on `HttpResponse` and returns the content (the response body) as a string.

Your data class should then somehow look like:

```
data class Films(val films: List<Film>) {
    data class Film(*...*)
}
```